# Using next Page token in YouTube API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I use nextPage token to upload more than 50 videos, in the same request or  do I have to add nextPage token to some other request to upload other videos. ,

Please provide a URL if that is required: android

Comment: Welcome to Stack we are here to help you fix problems with your code.  We do not supply URLs.

Answer (score 3):

> [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) Uploads **a** video to YouTube and optionally sets
>   the video's metadata.

As the documentation states you can only upload one video at a time.  Next page token is used for requests that can return more then the max number of rows like a get request.

Videos.insert returns a [videos resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) representing the video you just uploaded it does not contain a next link.

Note: I agree that the term video(s) may be misleading but this is the API we are given.

Side Note Batching uploading.  The YouTube API does support the [batch endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing).  I am not sure if you can get that to work with android or not.   I also think that the batching for upload will only upload the metadata for the video and not the video file itself.

Comment: FYI - the batch endpoint is part of the deprecated v2 YouTube Data API